# Openlayers polygon doesn't 'finish' drawing

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am trying to draw a freeform polygon in openlayers using the following code:

```
drawPolygon = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(layer, OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon, {eventListeners:{"featureadded": newPolygonAdded}});
```

However, I am having a problem where the polygon won't 'finish' drawing.  To clarify, I mean that usually when you double click a vertex, the polygon finishes drawing. With this code however, double clicking has no effect.  Please let me know if I am missing some crucial line that tells the handler we are 'done' drawing the polygon!  (I haven't seemed to find any such line in examples, and the code was working fine before when I was simply trying to draw a regular polygon instead of freeform). Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake: I'm not actually trying to draw a freeform polygon (just one where you can click to make vertices).  I just meant to differentiate it from the openlayers regular polygon.

Comment: What OpenLayers version are you using? Have you tried to omit the eventListeners hash (maybe there is an error in the newPolygonAdded func).

Comment: I have the same problem. feature never committed. I get the error: ol.js:634 Uncaught TypeError: this.lb.zb is not a function
    at Qt.k.Nd (ol.js:634)
    at Qt.Tt [as yf] (ol.js:629)
    at Qt.qg (ol.js:129)
    at Qt.St [as handleEvent] (ol.js:628)
    at G.k.uh (ol.js:285)
    at xe.b (ol.js:41)
    at xe.Dc.b (ol.js:44)
    at xe.k.vh (ol.js:89)
    at re.b (ol.js:41)
    at re.Dc.b (ol.js:44)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, not sure if its the same cause though...
My problem was that I couldn't end the path on my measure(line, polygon) tool when one of the default draw features was active at the same time. 
I had to change the default controls back to pan to end my measure tool path.

Don't know if its the same problem though...